# Laravel query - getting objects and their counts from related table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have table articles and it's related tables `comments`, `views` and `likes` which have a field `article_id` and in my function I am sending name of the related table, with `$request['option']`, comments for example, with ajax, to get the top 5 most commented articles. But in my function I am getting from the query result with `article_ids` and `counts` and then I am iterating through the results with foreach loop and getting article object with `article_id` that I am sending in the query. I would like to avoid doing that query for each of the results from the first query. What would be the way to do it more elegantly and without so many calls to DB?

This is my code:

```
public function mostArticle(Request $request) {
    $from = $request['from'];
    $to = $request['to'];

    $result = DB::table($request['option'])
                ->select(DB::raw('article_id'), DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
                ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', date($from).' 00:00:00')
                ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', date($to).' 00:00:00')
                ->groupBy('article_id')
                ->orderBy('count', 'DESC')
                ->take(5)
                ->get();

    foreach($result as $val){
      $article = Article::where('id', $val->article_id)->first();
      $mostSomethingArticle[$article->id] = [];
      $mostSomethingArticle[$article->id]['title'] = $article->title;
      $mostSomethingArticle[$article->id]['summary'] = $article->summary;
      $mostSomethingArticle[$article->id]['count'] = $val->count;
    }

    return json_encode($mostSomethingArticle);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use relations or joins. But im not sure, if this code is correct:

```
$result = DB::table($request['option'])
            ->select('article.id', 'article.title', 'article.summary',  DB::raw('count('.$request["option"].'.id) as count'))
            ->join('article', 'article.id', '=', $request['option']."article_id")
            ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', date($from).' 00:00:00')
            ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', date($to).' 00:00:00')
            ->groupBy('article_id')
            ->orderBy('count', 'DESC')
            ->take(5)
            ->get();

return $result;
```